# Where are "Standard Object Permissions" in Profiles?

Tags: permissions, profile, standard-objects

I can't find them. I'm an administrator.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Enhanced Profile Editor, they're grouped together under Object Settings. The "Standard Objects" and "Custom Objects" nomenclature only exists in the Classic Profile Editor. Note that for a Guest License, not all standard objects may be available, and some CRUD actions may be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Object Settings" (i.e. 3rd option under App Section)

Select the Object --> Click on Edit --> Assign Permissions